# Regex to check URL's

Tags: regex

```
I need to test for URLs with the below patterns:

https://cloudhusethelp.zendesk.com
https://cloudhusethelp.zendesk.com/
https://cloudhusethelp.zendesk.com/en-us
https://cloudhusethelp.zendesk.com/da
https://cloudhusethelp.zendesk.com/fr
https://cloudhusethelp.zendesk.com/aa
```

The regex used is `https\:\/\/cloudhusethelp\.zendesk\.com\/[A-z][A-z]`

So this compares the URL with 2 alphabets at the end. The URL can end with any language or no language.

Should I write multiple regular expression to find the match for above condition or one condition can do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand your problem.

Comment: @Jon Surrell need a help in writing regular expression which gives true for all the mentioned URL's

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do it with a single expression:

```
https\:\/\/cloudhusethelp\.zendesk\.com(\/[A-Za-z]{2}(-[A-Za-z]{2})?)?
```

The part that differs from your expression is at the end:

```
([A-Za-z]{2}(-[A-Za-z]{2})?)?
```

It is a nested optional expression that matches nothing, a pair of letters, or a pair of letters followed by dash and another pair of letters.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xG6rF9/2)

Answer (score 0):

the slash at the end is also optional, as the first example you provided dont have it.

```
https\:\/\/cloudhusethelp\.zendesk\.com(\/[A-z\-]{2}(\-[A-z\-]{2})?)?
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD8jP1/1)